# Is there a way to get Notepad++ to associate specific filenames with a language when they lack an extension?

Tags: notepad++, language

Several systems rely on files without extensions but with the same file names, such as [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) which uses `Vagrantfile` to define a set of VM boxes.

I know how to set up file extentions to match languages in Notepad++, but these files have no extensions (and adding one almost always causes problems). Is there a way to get Notepad++ to recognize these files by their file name, and use the appropriate language upon opening?

Comment: This might help too: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.editors.notepad%2B%2B/15628

Comment: Cannot vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Why would you mark this as a duplicate for a less-general question which lacked a suitable answer, then go answer the less-general question? Wouldn't it be better the other way around?

Comment: I don't see how this question is any different. It's the same question (they're even both about vagrant files even) and displays similar notes on what was tried. So in this case I went with age. I then found a possible solution so i posted it on the first instance of the question.

Comment: Fair enough. This question was meant to deal with all extensionless files and mention `Vagrantfile` as an example. But age before beauty.

Answer (score 0):

Seems N++ cannot do it.
In SynWrite app you can do. In lexer properties dialog enter not "ext" for extension but "/myfilename" for filename (with or without extension); example: "/vagrantfile".